# initialize and assign value to multiple variables vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, variables

there is the option to do this in vb.net

```
Dim a, b, c As Single, x, y As Double, i As Integer
```

also you can do

```
Dim myString = String.empty
```

Is there a way to initialize and assign multiple variables like the first example but using the assignment as the second one?

Comment: Do you *really* think such a coding style would be clearer than a separate statement per variable?

Comment: I am applying that style to a function already tested and well commented so I think in that case is good to do so

Comment: Absolutely not - just because a function is already tested and commented doesn't mean you should feel free to make the implementation unreadable. Declaring lots of variables - of different types, no less! - in the same statement *and* assigning them values - sounds like a way of making it take much longer to read and understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tested it in VS 2008, but I don't think that the Syntax of the Dim statement changed since. You will have to specify the type for each variable, if you initialize them

```
Dim a As Single = 1, b As Single = 2, x As Double = 5.5, y As Double = 7.5
```

Or you can let VB infer the type and use type characters (here `!` for `Single`):

```
Dim a = 1!, b = 2!, c = 3!, x = 5.5, y = 7.5, i = 100
```

By hovering with the cursor over the variables in VS you will see that the types are inferred correctly as `Single`, `Double` and `Integer`.
You could also use `F` for single. See: [Constant and Literal Data Types (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/constants-enums/constant-and-literal-data-types)

Answer (score 0):

I just now checked this code for multiple controls declaration in one line.
It compiled,and window appeared successfully.It was part of a a very big project.**`Dim DllNumber As New TextBox,DllMethod As New TextBox,LoopBox As New TextBox`
**
kvinvisibleguy